# How to make this shape in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes

I am not a graphic designer but I can do a few things in Illustrator.

My task is to convert the below image to a vector in Illustrator. I can do everything fine except the top blue shape. How would I do this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would draw 2 ellipses and then use Pathfinder to "Minus Front"

- Note that holding the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key down draws from the *center*... and....
- Holding the <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> *while* you are drawing allows you to reposition the object *while you draw* it.

I used both these and just *guessed* at where the center point of the first ellipse would be.

Then <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+drag to make a copy.

Switch to the **Free Transform** Tool, again holding the <kbd>Option</kbd> key to move both sides in unison.

Finally **Pathfinder > Minus Front** to remove the unnecessary parts.

This doesn't match the shape *exactly* but it **is** *far* more uniform than the original shape, while still maintaining the desired appearance. To me, the inconsistency in the original shape seemed to be an error, not intentional.

[image]

Comment: I had originally looked into that (and was gonna mention it), but since it wasn't the same shape, I decided to not even bring it up. *Though you are **100% correct** as far as symmetry.*

Comment: Based on the rather poor word space between "Auto" and "Glass" I can't help but feel the original wasn't created by a professional or at the very least, with much attention to detail..... So I think  the inconsistency in the shape is, to me, pretty clearly an error and imagine a more uniform appearance is desired. I will *often* correct visual errors such as this if reconstructing something.

Answer (score 3):

You can use auto trace for this (as it is a basic shape)

For more accurate (and controllable) results, use the pen tool: (<kbd>P</kbd>)

<sub>[Read more on the pen tool here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/drawing-pen-curvature-or-pencil.html)</sub>

[image]

<sub>Note: this was my 15 sec attempt at the pen tool, if you spend a few more minutes, you can get it really good</sub>

---

### Results:

[image]

> <sub>Scott's answer is *correct* as far as symmetry goes, my answer is considering that this shape is intentional and you are trying to recreate a perfect copy of this exact shape</sub>